# How file end of line and increase variable

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer

I have a problem with reading from file. I try read one verse and then increase variable.
My Input file looks like

> 2 4 5 6
>
> 1 3 8
>
> 2 8

My code to reading from file:

```
               while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                Integer k = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString());
                  tab[w][k-1]=1;    
                  w++;
```

So how increase w when I read one variable?

Comment: Side note: Why are you using the `Integer`? `int` would be much faster

Comment: Isn't that `w++;` is doing?  Perhaps you want to increase `w` when you read a line?

Comment: Variable w represent number of vertex. One line in file tell as what is the incidence of vertex e.g. Vertex 1 is in incidence with 2 4 5 6, vertex 2 with 1 3 8

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want two loops -- one for each line, and one for each "incidence" relationship within the line. With only one loop over a StringTokenizer, there's really no way to tell between a newline and other whitespace.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
String line;
for (int curLine = 0; (line = in.readLine()) != null; curLine ++) {
    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tok.hasMoreElements())
        tab[curLine][Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken()) - 1] = 1;
}
```